# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS - how to distinguish between table columns and view columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

My database has lots of tables and lots of views. For one of my tasks, I'm using this query. When I run following query it returns tons of columns - many of which belong to tables and many belong to views. **Question**: How can we distinguish which columns are from tables and which ones are from views:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
```

**Remark**: I'm using latest version SQL Server 2022

**Ref**. [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [INFORRMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql) view contains a `TABLE_TYPE` column, with a value of either "BASE TABLE" or "VIEW" to denote whether the object is a table or view. Join to this additional view like below to identify the object type:

```
 SELECT t.TABLE_TYPE, c.*
 FROM 
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
 JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t ON 
        t.TABLE_CATALOG = c.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME;
```